# C stuck inside for loop

Tags: c

So here's my code

```
int find_h(int i, int j, int current[N+1][N], int goal[N+1][N])
{
  int sum=0;
  int a, b;
  int cp[N*3], gp[N*3];
  for(a=0;a<N;a++)
  {
    for(b=0;b<N;b++)
    {
      cp[4*a+b]=current[a][b];
      gp[4*a+b]=goal[a][b];
      printf("b = %d\n", b);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return sum;
}
```

N=4 and current and goal are filled with the numbers from 0 to 15 inclusive, only appearing once each.

It loops fine the first 3 iterations (until a=3) but then it keeps outputting b = 0 forever.

Thanks

Comment: what is cp and gp used for? seems sum is never calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do, but I'll tell you something: `cp` and `gp` are too much small. As written, they should be big `N * N` instead of `N * 3` (== 12).

Now, here `cp[4*a+b]` you should have written `N*a+b`. If `N == 4` then it's the same. Otherwise...

And it isn't clear: `int current[N+1][N]` this will be (with `N == 4`) a 20 array element. You are then copying in a linearized array of `N * N` elements (or perhaps `N * 3`, see above)...

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I forgot to change that when I was testing

Comment: To be clear on why this turned into an infinite loop, it is likely that either `cp[13]` or `gp[13]` was actually pointing to `b` (because it happened to be right after that array in memory), and `current[3][1]` or `goal[3][1]` was `0`, so it kept setting `b` to `0` in a non-obvious way.  Definitely undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think your loop is overwriting memory.  if N = 4 then you are allocating cp[12] and gp[12].  Yet when a = 3 cp[4*a+b] and gp[4*a+b] both are [12] which is past the end of the array

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `cp` and `gp` are too small. You're assigning to elements with indices up to `4*(N-1)+(N-1)`, yet the arrays are only `3*N` elements long.

When you write past the end of the array, the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overflowing the cp and gp buffers. You should be allocating 4*N space for them, not 3*N. Can you try changing that? I would, but I'm away from my computer.